# Sequential FIFO queue for linux command line

Tags: linux, queue, sequential

I'm trying to find or implement a simple solution that can sequentially queue up Linux shell commands, so that they are executed one at a time.  Here are the criteria:

1. The queue must execute the commands one at a time, i.e. no two commands can run at the same time.
2. I don't have the list of commands ahead of time. They will be coming in from web requests that my web server receives. That means the queue could be empty for a long time, and 10 requests can come in at the same time.
3. My web server can only do system calls to the shell, so this program/solution needs to be callable from the command line.
4. I only have one machine, so it can't and doesn't need to farm out the work to multiple machines.

Originally I thought the `at` command can do what I want, but the only thing is that it doesn't execute the commands sequentially.

I'm thinking of implementing my own solution in python with these parts:

1. Have a dedicated directory with a lock file
2. Queued commands are stored as individual files with the filename containing an incrementing sequence ID or timestamp or something similar, which I'll call "command files"
3. Write a python script using `fcntl` module on the lock file to ensure only 1 instance of the script is running
4. The script will watch the directory for any files and execute the shell commands in the files in the order of the filename
5. When the directory has no more "command files", the script will unlock the lock file and exit
6. When my web server wants to enqueue jobs, it will add a new "command file" and call my python script
7. The python script will check if another instance of itself is running. If yes, then exit, which will let the other instance handle the newly queued "command file". If no, then lock the lock file and start executing the "command files" in order

Does this sound like it'll work?  The only race condition that I don't know how to handle is when the first instance of the script checks the directory and see that it's empty, and before it unlocks the lock file, a new command is queued and new instance of the script invoked.  And that new script will exit when it sees the file is locked.  Then the original script will unlock the file and exit.

Is there something out there that already do this, so I don't have to implement this myself?

Comment: You're seriously going to let web users run shell commands on your system?  What happens the first time somebody runs `rm -rf *`?

Comment: Nope. I'm running my own shell commands based on information supplied by the user in a form submission, from which I generate my own params into my shell script.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a named pipe, aka FIFO:

```
mkfifo /tmp/shellpipe
```

Start a shell process whose input comes from the pipe:

```
/bin/sh < /tmp/shellpipe
```

When the web server wants to execute a command, it writes it to the pipe.

```
sprintf(cmdbuf, "echo '%s' > /tmp/shellpipe", command);
system(cmdbuf);
```

Answer (score 2):

A [posix message queue](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/mq_overview.7.html) seems tailor made for this and whole lot simpler (and faster) than messing around with timestamped files and such.  A script can enqueue the requests when they come in; another script dequeues the requests and executes them.  There are some size limitations that apply to the queues but it doesn't sound like you would come close to hitting them.